# Java 8 lambda adding to a list in a Hashmap, in a Hashmap

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-8

I have a `List<POJO>` that I want to extract data from and the variables I'm interested in are:

- `Environment: String`
- `Application: String`
- `Throughput: Double`

There are 7 `Environment` objects and each `Environment` has 18 `Application` objects, which each have multiple `values`.

I'm trying to iterate over the `List<POJO>` and store these values in a `Hashmap<Environment.ToString, Hashmap<Applications.ToString, List<Double>>`

I'm trying to use Java 8's Lambda features; my code so far:

```
private HashMap<String, List<BigDecimal>> appMap = new HashMap<String, List<BigDecimal>>();
private HashMap<String, HashMap> envMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();

for(POJO chartModel: List<POJO>) {
    appMap.computeIfAbsent(chartModel.getName(), v -> new ArrayList<BigDecimal>())
          .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(chartModel.getThroughput()));
    envMap.put(chartModel.getEnvironment(), appMap);
}
```

Firstly, is there a shorthand way to iterate over the `List` inside the inner `Map` using `Java8`?

Secondly, my code isn't quite right, so currently the map adds all the `Throughput` values to its `Application` key, so I end up with 18 keys with a list of values.

What I need it to do is in my `envMap` I should have 7 `Environment` objects, with each having its 18 `Application` objects and values, so there would be 126 `Application` objects in total. Can this be achieved the way I'm attempting it, is there a Lambda way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you only have one instance of `appMap`, and that's going to be inserted into the `envMap` 7 times, once for each `Environment`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use 2 grouping by operations: the first one groups according to the environment and the second one groups according to the name. Finally, you need to map each values to the `BigDecimal` value of their throughput.

Assuming `pojo` is a `List<POJO>`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<BigDecimal>>> result =
    pojo.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            POJO::getEnvironment,
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                POJO::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(p -> BigDecimal.valueOf(p.getThroughput()), Collectors.toList())
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are creating only one `Map`, `appMap`, which you are putting into `envMap` for every key. You obviously want to create a new `Map` for each distinct key and you already know the right tool, `computeIfAbsent`. But you should also mind the [“diamond operator”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html). While not being a new Java 8 feature, your code will clearly benefit from removing the repetitions of the type parameters. Putting it all together, the operation will look like:

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, List<BigDecimal>>> envMap = new HashMap<>();
for(POJO chartModel: list) {
    envMap.computeIfAbsent(chartModel.getEnvironment(), env -> new HashMap<>())
        .computeIfAbsent(chartModel.getName(), name -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(chartModel.getThroughput()));
}
```

You can also express the same logic using the Stream API, [as shown by Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872708/2711488), but you don’t need to.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using one method over the other?

Comment: In this specific case, there are no important differences. You can use whatever you like but it’s worth knowing *both* ways.

Comment: I would actually prefer this solution, as here we have less nested calls. Five closing parentheses in a row is too much.